# Nullable (int?) keep throwing non-nullable exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a first that I've encountered this - of course that does't sais a lot, but never the less I need to consult with the collective as my searches while showed that it can be done, I'm not able to work it out.

The issue is that if user leaves the text box empty C# automagically enters zero on the postback and into the database as well. I just want the text box left blank.

I have a class there the property is declared:

```
private int? _PageNumber = null;

public int? PageNumber
{
    get { return _PageNumber; }
    set { _PageNumber = value; }
}
```

The in my code file I have:

```
if (tbPageNumber.Text != "")
        ia.PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(tbPageNumber.Text);
    else
        ia.PageNumber = null;
```

and this is where I get the exception:

```
CS0037: Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type
```

So I thought if I can't change the type, perhaps I can change the output. So I thought perhaps I can fake it by placing this in the texbox's text property:

```
'<%# Eval("PageNumber") == 0 ? null:Eval("PageNumber") %>'
```

This throws `CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'` exception.

Why is so damn stubborn???

Comment: That doesn't sound like an exception - that sounds like a compile-time problem. Can you reproduce this in a short but complete console app, to task ASP.NET out of the picture?

Comment: CS0037 looks more like a compiler error than an exception. There is a really big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay people, you gonna kill me for this.

The issue was that the class in which the `ia.PageNumber` is declared in a separate project in the solution and for some reason it did't compile, hence the comments about compiler-time problems.

This is a first such solution with multiple projects that I've worked with and I had no reason to think to compile individual projects (I use Visual Studio 2010).

Well, lesson learned. Many thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 5):

To be very straight forward, there is no way that `ia.PageNumber` is referring to the definition you provided because the following code not only compiles, **and runs**, but writes out `Setting to NULL.`:

```
private int? _PageNumber = null;

public int? PageNumber
{
    get { return _PageNumber; }
    set { _PageNumber = value; }
}

if (string.Empty != "")
{
    PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine("Setting to value.");
}
else
{
    PageNumber = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Setting to NULL.");
}
```

the bottom line is that `ia.PageNumber` isn't `int?` **or** _PageNumber isn't an `int?`. To further concrete my position, the following code:

```
PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(" ");
Console.WriteLine("Setting to value {0}.", PageNumber);
```

throws the expected exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

so the problem can't be a padded string either. And to finally concrete my position, the following code:

```
PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32("");
Console.WriteLine("Setting to value {0}.", PageNumber);
```

throws the expected exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

so the problem can't be an empty string either. And to further concrete this position based on the comment made by `jadarnel27` that you might be converting `null`, that actually succeeds as expected, the following code:

```
PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(null);
Console.WriteLine("Setting to value {0}.", PageNumber);
```

actually, compiles, runs, and throws no execption. It outputs the string `Setting to value 0.` as expected.

Comment: If tbPageNumber.Text is null, then the OPs code is calling Convert.ToInt32 on null, which seems like it might be the problem he's experiencing.  His if check doesn't account for null, just for empty.

Comment: @jadarnel27, that's actually not correct, please see my edit.

Comment: Ah. My mistake.  I thought I remembered converting null not working, but I see from the docs that is incorrect.

Comment: @jadarnel27: CS0037 is a compile error while the potential error you pointed out whouldn't occur until runtime

Comment: @Cemafor Yep, I got mixed up.  As I said above... "*My mistake*" ...=)

Comment: @jadarnel27: Yeah, sorry. You added that comment beforfe my page refreshed. It is still a case the OP probably wants to take into account, even if it wont blow up.

Comment: Michael - great analysis.  In case you didn't see, the OP [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933052/nullable-int-keep-throwing-non-nullable-exception/15934918#15934918) saying this was basically user error =)

Answer (score 4):

I would try the following:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPageNumber.Text))
    ia.PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(tbPageNumber.Text);
else
    ia.PageNumber = null;
```

An empty string and a null string are two different things, therefore a string with null value could be slipping through your code.

Comment: But the problem is not with `null` or `empty` string, that's all about how to save `null` in `int` data type.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the `OP` is getting a compiler error. The bottom line is that `ia.PageNumber` **is not** an `int?`.

Comment: @jvanh1, it's literally not possible. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I made an extension method for this which helps me out a lot with these web-related string conversions in case of value types:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T As<T>(this string input, T fallback = default(T), 
                          IFormatProvider provider = null)
    {
        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
        if (type == null)
            type = typeof(T);
        T result;
        try
        {
            result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, type, provider);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            result = fallback;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ia.PageNumber = tbPageNumber.Text.As<int>();
ia.PageNumber = tbPageNumber.Text.As<int?>();
ia.PageNumber = tbPageNumber.Text.As<int?>(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ia.PageNumber = (int?)null;
```

Edit: I was thinking of a different issue.. The error indicates that `ia.PageNumber` is an `int`, not an `int?`, despite the sample code provided.

Comment: What difference it will make?

Answer (score 0):

**CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'**

Try this 0 to "0"

```
'<%# Eval("PageNumber") == "0" ? 0:Eval("PageNumber") %>'
```

**Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type**

Don't use null in `pagenumber` .Because the `pagenumber` property get only integer values.But null is not a integer. So you get this above  error.But **now I changed from null to 0**

Comment: I do not want zero to display.